# Error 400 'bad request' when trying to cURL RSS feed

Tags: php, http, curl, rss, feed

I'm trying to scrape the below feed (with permission) via PHP cURL:

```
http://www.safc.com/Home/RSS Feeds/News%20Feed
```

Loads fine in a browser, but gives me a 400 'bad request' with cURL.

```
$ch = curl_init($uri); //http://www.safc.com/Home/RSS Feeds/News%20Feed
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => CURL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => CURL_USER_AGENT,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

Result is a 400; I know this from looking in `curl_getinfo()`.

`CURL_USER_AGENT` is an arbitrary identifier as I realised some other feeds wouldn't spit out content unless this header was present. I have tried removing the headers one by one, and tried adding a few more, but that approach feels a bit needle/haystack.

Before I approach the owners of the site, does anyone know how I might resolve this?

Comment: use http://www.safc.com/home/rss%20feeds/news%20feed check different between "Home" and "home" there is 301 redirect when you use "Home".

Comment: Man do I feel silly. I tried that, but only with the second space - I didn't spot the first one. Post this up as an answer and I'll give you the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://www.safc.com/home/rss%20feeds/news%20feed check different between "Home" and "home" there is 301 redirect when you use "Home".